# ElasticSearch - order with min in aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have objects in the index that are related by an id, which groups them.
The group creation time is the time between the min `createdAt` object in the group and the max `createdAt` object in the group.

I'd like to order these groups by the min or max time, how can I do this?

```
{
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{
      "intervals":{
         "composite":{
            "size":10000,
            "sources":[
               {
                  "totalId":{
                     "terms":{
                        "field":"totalId"
                     }
                  },
                  "name": {
                    "terms":{
                        "field":"name"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         "aggs": {
          "createdAtStart": {
            "min": {"field": "createdAt", "format": "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ssZ"}, "order": { "createdAtStart": "desc" }
          },
          "createdAtEnd": {
            "max": {"field": "createdAt", "format": "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ssZ"}
          }
      }
   }
}
```

I'm using order wrong:

> Found two aggregation type definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve that with a `composite` aggregation because the `terms` source is not orderable by the values of a sub-aggregation, like it is the case with a "normal" `terms` aggregation. (also the date formats are wrong)

So the correct query that will give you want you want is this one:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "totalId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "totalId",
        "order": {
          "createdAtStart": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "createdAtStart": {
          "min": {
            "field": "createdAt",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
          }
        },
        "createdAtEnd": {
          "max": {
            "field": "createdAt",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Because of the way the composite aggregation works, it's not possible to achieve what you want. The reason is that the composite aggregation has been created in order to "paginate" over a big amount of buckets. That pagination is defined by the way the buckets are ordered. If it was possible to sort buckets according to sub-aggregations, it would mean that all buckets would need to be pre-computed and pre-sorted before returning the first page of results, which would completely defeat the purpose of this aggregation.

Comment: `[terms] order doesn't support values of type: START_OBJECT` when trying the solution

Comment: Is it not possible with composite aggregation? I need multiple fields in the aggregation

Comment: You didn't mention that initially. But no, it's not, because of the way the composite aggregation works. I've explained in more details in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an extra `{`

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "intervals": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 10000,
        "sources": [
          {
            "totalId": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "totalId"
              }
            }
          }
        ]                                    <-- note this
      },
      "aggs": {
        "createdAtStart": {
          "min": {
            "field": "createdAt",
            "format": "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
          },
          "order": {
            "createdAtStart": "desc"
          }
        },
        "createdAtEnd": {
          "max": {
            "field": "createdAt",
            "format": "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is just a typo in my example, not the main issue -  fixed